# Mysql: Union of two select queries that are ordered and grouped

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql queries that I would like to combine (but excluding duplicates). But since both of them use group and order I get an error when I use `UNION`.

Query 1:

```
 SELECT deals.id, deals.stage, deals.property_id,
   -> SUM(callbacks.created_at < '2022-07-06 16:59:21') AS
   -> due_soon_callbacks_sum FROM `deals` INNER JOIN `requests` ON
   -> `requests`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`id` INNER JOIN `callbacks` ON
   -> `callbacks`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id` WHERE
   -> (callbacks.overdue_at > '2022-07-07 16:59:21')
   -> GROUP BY `deals`.`id` ORDER BY `due_soon_callbacks_sum` DESC
```

Query 2

```
 SELECT deals.id, deals.stage, deals.property_id,
   -> SUM(callbacks.created_at < '2022-07-06 16:59:21') AS
   -> due_soon_callbacks_sum FROM `deals` INNER JOIN `requests` ON
   -> `requests`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`id` INNER JOIN `callbacks` ON
   -> `callbacks`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id` WHERE
   -> (callbacks.overdue_at < '2022-07-07 16:59:21')
   -> GROUP BY `deals`.`id` ORDER BY `due_soon_callbacks_sum` DESC
```

- The only difference between Query 1 and Query 2 is
  `callbacks.overdue_at < '2022-07-07 16:59:21'` vs
  `callbacks.overdue_at > '2022-07-07 16:59:21'`
- I need to have **the records of query 1 first followed by the records of query 2** (excluding the ones that are already given by query 1). I assume I need another `GROUP BY`, but I am not advanced enough to know how to do it
- I tried simply using `UNION` between them, but I get `(1221, 'Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY')`
- I tried using an `OR` like this `WHERE (callbacks.overdue_at > ... OR callbacks.overdue_at < ...) GROUP BY deals.id ORDER BY due_soon_callbacks_sum DESC` but this does not preserve the order that I want

Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap each query within a `SELECT  * FROM (your-query) AS table1 UNION ...` to workaround the 1221 error. Then you could order the result of the 2 unions with the same idea.

Comment: @goldman - it gets rid of the error but it does not preserve the order I need...

Comment: @Luuk I don't really get your comment, could you pls post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to keep the results of the first and the second query separated.

The query will like this:

```
( SELECT 
   1 as noq,
   deals.id, 
   deals.stage, 
   deals.property_id,
   SUM(callbacks.created_at < '2022-07-06 16:59:21') AS due_soon_callbacks_sum 
FROM `deals` 
INNER JOIN `requests` ON `requests`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `callbacks` ON `callbacks`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id`
WHERE (callbacks.overdue_at > '2022-07-07 16:59:21'))

UNION ALL

( SELECT 
   2 as noq,
   deals.id, 
   deals.stage, 
   deals.property_id,
   SUM(callbacks.created_at < '2022-07-06 16:59:21') AS due_soon_callbacks_sum 
FROM `deals` 
INNER JOIN `requests` ON `requests`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `callbacks` ON `callbacks`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id`
WHERE (callbacks.overdue_at < '2022-07-07 16:59:21')
GROUP BY `deals`.`id` ORDER BY `due_soon_callbacks_sum` DESC )

ORDER BY noc, `due_soon_callbacks_sum` DESC
```